# Discord js no role added

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hi I am following a tutorial on Youtube but I can't figure out why it's not working. Can someone explain to me why it isn't working?

There are no errors in the console but the role doesn't get added

Comment: Can you describe how "doesn't work" means? Was an error thrown, or was your code malfunctioning, or maybe it doesn't even get called? This can make a very big difference in answers.

Comment: there are no errors in the console but the role doesn't get added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `discord.js^12.x` module, I can still see you use `member.removeRoles()` and `member.addRoles()`, which are `deprecated`. And also, the `member` variable you made was a `user` property not a `guildMember` property. Try to follow the code below:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'coloradd',
    description: 'Give You Your Color',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        const colors = message.guild.roles.cache.filter(c => c.name.startsWith('#'))
        let str = args.join(' ')
        let role = colors.find(role => role.name.slice(1).toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase());
        if (!role) {
            return message.channel.send('That color doens\'t exist')
        } try {
            const member = message.member; // Use `message.member` instead to get the `guldMember` property.
            // `addRoles()` and `removeRoles()` are deprecated.
            member.roles.remove(colors);
            member.roles.add(role);
            message.channel.send('Your Have Received Your Color !')
        } catch (e) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Error')
                .setColor('RED')
                .setDescription('There is an error with the role Hierarchy Or my permissions. Make Sure I am above the color roles')
            return (embed)
        }
    }
}
```

Visit these guides to help you understand more about the subject:

- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Changes from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)
- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Adding a role to a guildMember](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-add-a-role-to-a-guild-member)
- [Discord.js.org - Docs - guildMember Property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)
- [Discord.js.org - Docs - User Property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)